# Writing an Excel Addin User Guide

Tags: excel, add-in

I've created an addin for Excel containing a number of different functions. Now, I need to create a user guide (a set of webpages will suffice) defining what the functions do; their inputs and their outputs.

Are there any tools that will help me do this? Has anyone seen any good examples recently, or shall I just mimic Excel Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx) has a documentation generation tool for VBA and VB6. It might give you a good start, at least.

Answer (score 0):

http://xll.codeplex.com generates .chm files that are integrated into Excel.